# When does Mystogan defeat all of the Phantom Guild's subdivisions?

Tags: fairy-tail

On the Fairy Tail Wikia, on the page [Magic Staves](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Magic_Staves), it says that Mystogan defeated all of the Phantom Guild's subdivisions by himself. However, I don't remember when this occurred. Which episodes was this from?

From this information, I have come to the conclusion that the episode would most likely be during the Phantom Guild Arc, but I still can't find it.

Comment: He single-handedly took down all of Phantom Lord's sub-divisions during the guild war and directly confronted Laxus when the latter attempted to forcibly take control of the guild.

Comment: So is it actually during the fighting festival arc?

Comment: When mystogan single handily took down all of Phantom Lords subdivisions.

Comment: Indeed, this happened during the Fighting Festival arc. Not the phantom guild arc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mystogan defeated the subdivisions of Phantom Lord during the [Phantom Lord Arc.](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Phantom_Lord_arc)

Manga chapters 47-69 and Anime episodes 21-30.

This is a snapshot from chapter 65 of the manga : Fairy Law. The anime should too have it in the same episode named Fairy Law.

[image]

Quote from the wiki linked above:

> Just then, she notices Mystogan sitting quietly not far from her, who
>   asks her for apples, and she realizes that the reason Makarov managed
>   to heal so quickly was because the mysterious S-Class Mage gathered
>   his scattered Magic power. **She proceeds to lecture him for not joining
>   the battle and helping out his comrades, but then the wind starts
>   blowing and scatters numerous flags with Phantom's emblem on them
>   around. Porlyusica realizes Mystogan did more than enough by taking
>   out all of Phantom's subdivisions single-handedly**, and the two remain
>   still, discussing the situation enigmatically.

Note: Emphasis mine.